# Find pre/post-decessor in pandas for each group

Tags: python, pandas

To reduce the complexity, I reworked the whole post:

So, what do I want to achieve:
For a list of campaigns with given start at end dates, I want to return the previous campaign. Previous means that a campaign starts after the end day of the previous one. However, if there are several previous campaings, I want to return the campaign with the same type. This shall be done for every campaign I have (typically, I will have grouped data, (think of item/campaign pairs, where one campaing has several items and I'm interested in the previous campaign for a single item)

Consider the following data

```
Campaign | StartDay | EndDay | Type
---------|----------|--------|------
    1    |    1     |   10   |  1
    2    |    5     |   15   |  1
    3    |    7     |   15   |  2
    4    |   11     |   20   |  1
    5    |   16     |   25   |  2
```

So in this case, the desired output is the following

```
Campaign | PreviousCampaign
---------|-----------------
    1    |     NAN
    2    |     NAN
    3    |     NAN
    4    |      1
    5    |      3
```

If the first entries vanish, it's ok. Note that the predecessor of 5 is 3 due to the type condition.

I'm able to do this merging the table on itself via campaign, querying the correct rows and several steps to ensure that the type costraint is satisfied.
Without the type type constraint this is a bit easier.

However, studying "modern pandas" by tom augspurger, I have the feeling that pivoting, stacking, melting or a combination should work. But I haven't figured out how, yet.

Comment: Can you show your desired output?

Comment: updated it, and changed the example for item 2 slighlty

Comment: The desired output helps, but it's still hard to follow the logic you want.  Is the "reference campaign" what you want in the "NextCampaign" column?  This might be clearer if you can explain why you want to do this.

Comment: hey, I rewrote and shortened the example. I hope it's more focussed now on the essential parts

Comment: Much clearer.  But what should happen if there are two previous campaigns with the same type?

Comment: good question: simple way: pick the "first" campaign (with smaller number, appearing first). Additionally, one could use further columns and a function to decide which column to pick. However, also in that case, it might happen that one has to simply pick one element like in the simple way